# What attributes, at a minimum, do I need to override when creating slaves?

Tags: algolia

[Documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/ruby#multiple-sort-criteria) is confusing with respect to which attributes should be overriden when creating slaves. It appears that `customRanking` is the only field that Algolia recommends overriding. All other attributes will be copied from primary index at the time slave is created.

How about `attributesForFaceting` and `attributesToIndex`? Does the slave need to set them explicitly or are they inherited from parent by default?

Answer (score 1):

When you attach/create a new slave, it will automatically inherit from all the settings of the master index. But then, you're free to update the slave settings the way you want.

The common use-case of using slaves is to handle the "sort by " case, because the sort order is statically defined at indexing-time (so you need 1 slave per sort). To do so, you can put the numerical attribute you want to sort your records with on top of the Ranking formula (above all the other criteria).